# Fork Git Client Update AWS Credentials

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, aws-credentials

I'm currently using the Fork git client (git-fork.com) (I'm not sure that matters though) and I'm pushing changes to AWS for a client. When I did the initial pull it asked me for my Amazon credentials and everything was working ok. Recently we had some issues with AWS suddenly throwing 403 permission errors, so the client revoked my Amazon login details and sent me new ones.

Is there a way (maybe a cmd command?) that revokes my AWS credentials in Fork so that on the next push/pull I have to enter the details again? I just can't seem to find a way to tell the Git client I want to refresh my AWS details. Does my client need to do anything in their Amazon account?

Hope that has made some sense and thank you very much for any help,
K.

Comment: Supremely bad name for a git client.

Comment: Yes, it is really. Makes searching a bit difficult. I can always contact the software authors. Also, maybe re-adding the repository might work. It just seems like it should be a fairly standard thing to accomplish?

Comment: I did try cloning the repo again, but still got a 403 response. Maybe the issue is with AWS.

Comment: Have you had success with a traditional git client? Just wondering if making that work first would be simpler. Personally I prefer to use [SSH keys](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_ssh-keys.html) for git repo access. It's proven to be less painful than HTTPS and credential provider-based options for me.

Comment: I also have GitExtensions and will try that to see if it works, but yes, the client suggested we switch to SSH keys, so if we can't figure out this 403 problem, we will give that a try. Thanks.

Comment: Def looks like an aws issue as GitExtensions fails to clone as well with the 403 error. Trying SSH now.

Comment: SSH works, so back to normal. Thanks for the comments, appreciate it.